# Using System.Management in my executable

Tags: c#, reference, wmi

New to C# and have an console application that accesses Windows WMI. I added:

```
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Instrumentation;
```

Also added the reference and set "CopyToLocal" to true on both references. I do see the two .dll's in the "bin/debug" directory, however, when running on another computer (where I did not compile the source on), I still get the error that the two references are not found.

Can anyone help? Sorry, I am sure this is a very basic question.
[image]

The exception that I get is:

> Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access id denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESS_DENIED) at System.Runtime.InteropService.Marshal.ThrowExcetpionForHRInternal(Int32 errorcCode, IntPtr, errorInfo) at System.Runtime.InteropService.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode) at System.Management.ManagementScope.InitializeGuts(Object o) at System.Management.ManagementScrope.Initialize() at System.Management.ManagementScropt.Connect()

I truly appreciate all the help!

Comment: are you just copying the .exe or the whole debug folder to the other computer?

Comment: You'll never get an error that says "the two references are not found".  Do not set Copy Local to true, do quote the *exact* error message.

Comment: I tried both - just copying the ".exe" which is my preferred method, and the entire project folder. The actual error is: Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access id denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESS_DENIED) at System.Runtime.InteropService.Marshal.ThrowExcetpionForHRInternal(Int32 errorcCode, IntPtr, errorInfo) at System.Runtime.InteropService.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode) at System.Management.ManagementScope.InitializeGuts(Object o) at System.Management.ManagementScrope.Initialize() at System.Management.ManagementScropt.Connect()

Comment: I've copied the exception message to the question to make it easier for somebody to see it.

Answer (score 0):

See the following YouTube Clip - worked like a charm (C# How To Embed And Reference An External Assembly (DLL) - Windows Forms)     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-KK7bmo1AM